Looking for an affordable cm level accuracy RTK GPS module for ROS slam project
This is my first time here. I'm thinking about a ROS project.
I want to record RTK GPS information and visual + IMU data simultaneously in a rosbag file.
Can you please suggest an affordable RTK GPS module?
I'm thinking about:

simpleRTK2B Budget
u-blox GNSS Multiband antenna ANN-MB-00 (IP67))

My primary purpose for that module is to find accurate ground truth. Also, the GPS data (cm level accuracy) can be recorded simultaneously in a rosbag file along with the Camera and IMU data using Intel Realsense D455. I want to sync all the data in a bag file.
I'm new to the GPS system. My question is if I choose the right GPS module.

Just to record the GPS data (Langitute, Lattitude) is only one simpleRTK2B Budget module enough for the cm level accuracy?

Will I able be to record the data simultaneously along with the D455 data in rosbag?


I'm in a hurry to research all of this because I need to get this GPS module from someone else who is coming to my country very soon.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.
